# Google Analytics - Get nested span event click without class and id

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events, google-tag-manager

I am using Tag manager and Anayltics 360.
My code as follows,

```
<div rel="ABC_Links" class="ak_widget" >
<!-- BEGIN: Widget - Links -->
<section class="mfb-30">
    <div class="widget_links">
        <div class="widget_container">
            <div class="widget_content">
                <button type="button" class="buttonShadow" onclick="window.open('https://somepagelink.aspx); return false;">
                    <div class="widget_item">
                        <div class="widget_icon">
                            <svg>123</svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget_text"><span style="overflow-wrap: normal;">ABCD TEXT</span></div>
                    </div>
                </button>

               <button type="button" class="buttonShadow" onclick="window.open('https://somepagelink.aspx); return false;">
                    <div class="widget_item">
                        <div class="widget_icon">
                            <svg> 12345</svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget_text"><span style="overflow-wrap: normal;">XYZ TEXT</span></div>
                    </div>
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- END: Widget Links --></div>
```

I have 12 buttons in this same format. Here i have given an example of two buttons.
Button name i can change later so i can not take it as hard coded for "Click Text" in tag manager.
I can use only rel= "ABC_Links" as unique identifier. I can not use any of below class as they are not unique.
I have used Custome javascript to get parent child relationship but didn't work.
I have used DOM element variable but it did not work.

Now Question is, Is there any way to trigger event in tag manager when i click on any of the button below and get the info in real time event in Anayltics 360 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to create a User-Defined Custom JavaScript variable in GTM to set isABCLink=true on button click.

1. On the Variables screen under Built-In Variables make sure you have "Click Element" ticked.
2. Create a User-Defined Variable
   Name: isABCLink
   Type: Custom JavaScript
   Code:

   ```
   function() {
     return {{Click Element}}.matches("div[rel=ABC_Links] button, div[rel=ABC_Links] button *");
   }
   ```
3. Create a Trigger
   Trigger Type: Click - All Elements
   This trigger fires on: Some Clicks
   Conditions: isABCLink equals true
4. Set up your tag firing on above trigger

Once caveat to point out is that the exact element clicked on could be the button or one of the child elements of the button such as the <svg> which might make it hard to set up your tag depending on what exactly you need.